# MOVQ gives strange result

Tags: gcc, gdb, x86-64

`movq (rax), rbx`

RAX holds a memory address that stores value 12.
I use gdb to debug. After I execute this instruction, in gdb

> p $rbx gives 77309411340
> p *($rax) gives 12.

Could folks help me with this? Shouldn't RBX be equal to 12?

Comment: The least significant byte of `77309411340` has the value 12.

Comment: Did you mean `mov (%rax), %rbx`?  WIthout the % decorators, it's not valid AT&T syntax.

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry about that, I mean %rax, not rax.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I wrote 32-bit wide data to memory, however, I read 64-bit wide data afterward.